# Trouble populating spinner from ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have an ArrayList containing strings that are read in from a text file. I want these strings to populate a spinner but my code doesn't work and it's saying "Cannot resolve constructor" when I hover over the line:

```
ArrayAdapter adp = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, devicesAL);
```

Here is the rest of my code, I have provided all of it because I do not know where the cause is. This particular bit is in the second try block. Can anyone please help?

```
package com.example.iotdevicestatus;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String statusLink = "http://redacted.uk/pmt/status.txt";
    String deviceLink = "http://redacted.uk/pmt/devices.txt";
    String status = "status testttest";

    ArrayList<String> devicesAL = new ArrayList<>();



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    // Set up connection to device.txt on web server
                    URL deviceUrl = new URL (deviceLink);
                    URLConnection deviceConn = deviceUrl.openConnection();
                    deviceConn.setDoOutput(true);
                    deviceConn.connect();

                    InputStream dis = deviceConn.getInputStream();
                    InputStreamReader disr = new InputStreamReader(dis, "UTF-8");
                    BufferedReader dbr = new BufferedReader(disr);

                    String deviceLine;

                    // Set up connection to status.txt on web server
                    URL statusUrl = new URL(statusLink);
                    URLConnection statusConn = statusUrl.openConnection();
                    statusConn.setDoOutput(true);
                    statusConn.connect();

                    InputStream sis = statusConn.getInputStream();
                    InputStreamReader sisr = new InputStreamReader(sis, "UTF-8");
                    BufferedReader sbr = new BufferedReader(sisr);

                    String statusLine;


                    try {

                        while ((deviceLine = dbr.readLine()) != null) {
                            System.out.println(deviceLine);
                            devicesAL.add(deviceLine);

                            Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
                            ArrayAdapter adp = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, devicesAL);
                            adp.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                            spinner.setAdapter(adp);
                        }

                        while ((statusLine = sbr.readLine()) != null) {
                            System.out.println(statusLine);
                            status = statusLine;

                            System.out.println("Status = " + status);
                            //al.add(line); - use in case of multiple statuses

                            TextView output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

                            System.out.println(status);

                            output.setText(status);
                        }


                        for (String str : devicesAL) {
                            System.out.println(str);
                        }


                    } finally {
                        sbr.close();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        thread.start();



    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that you do not have `ArrayAdapter` imported, or you do not have some requirement in your `Gradle`

Comment: Cannot resolve constructor 'ArrayAdapter(anonymous java.lang.Runnable, int, java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>)'

Comment: look at @m0skit0 answer

Answer (score 1):

Note that `this` inside an anonymous class refers to that anonymous class. What you want is the instance of `MainActivity`, not of `Runnable` anonymous subclass.

```
ArrayAdapter adp = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, devicesAL);
```

---

Since your Spinner is still not populated, you can

1. Make sure `devicesAL` is populated
2. Call `adp.notifyDataSetChanged()` after populating and setting the adapter to the Spinner.
3. Run everything related to modifying UI inside `Activity#runOnUiThread()`.

Comment: This removed the error, but broke the program and didn't populate the spinner.

Comment: @JB2000 That's a different problem/question. Your question is about the constuctor error, which I answered.

Comment: My question was not specifically about the constructor error, I gave that error to help others in finding my problem. I am left with the same problem I started with as I cannot populate my spinner.

Comment: In your first sentence: *"but my code doesn't work and it's saying "Cannot resolve constructor"*. Anyway I updated my question with other solution you can try.